# R regular expression to obtain all text before the second underscore

Tags: regex, r, split

```
s <- "1-343-43Hello_2_323.14_fdh-99H"
```

In R I want to use a regex to get the substring before the, say 2nd, underscore. How can this be done with one regex ? The alternative would be to split by '_' and then paste the first two - something along;

```
paste(sapply(strsplit(s, "_"),"[", 1:2), collapse = "_")
```

Gives:

```
[1] "1-343-43Hello_2"
```

But how can I make a regex expression to do the same ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `sub`:

```
sub("^([^_]*_[^_]*).*", "\\1", s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tS6gL4/1)

[R code demo](https://ideone.com/qUeiOB):

```
s <- "1-343-43Hello_2_323.14_fdh-99H"
sub("^([^_]*_[^_]*).*", "\\1", s)
## => [1] "1-343-43Hello_2"
```

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `([^_]*_[^_]*)` - Group 1 capturing 0+ characters other than `_`, then a `_` and again 0+ non-`_`s
- `.*` - rest of the string (note that the TRE regex `.` matches newlines, too).

The `\\1` replacement only returns the value inside Group 1.

Answer (score 9):

In general, for answering to the question in title, is

```
sub("^(([^_]*_){n}[^_]*).*", "\\1", s)
```

where `n` is the number of `_` you are allowing.

Comment: Actually `n` is the number of underscores minus 1 so if you want to allow 2 underscores then n is 1.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck No, it isn't.

Comment: You are right but the question refers to " the substring before the, say 2nd, underscore" and for that n=1, not 2, and that was what I was trying to clarify but clearly mistated it.  I did give you an upvote in any case for providing the most general answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
sub('\\_\\d+\\..*$','',s)
#[1] "1-343-43Hello_2"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_replace("/([^_])_([^_]).*/" , "$1_$2" , "1-343-43Hello_2_323.14_fdh-99H");
```

Or if you are looking for just matching int /^[^*]**[^_]*/ would be the regex string to match it

```
<?php
    echo preg_match("/^[^_]*_[^_]*/" , "1-343-43Hello_2_323.14_fdh-99H" , $test );
    var_dump( $test );
?>
```

or in javascript

```
"1-343-43Hello_2_323.14_fdh-99H".match(/^[^_]*_[^_]*/);
```

Comment: The question was explicitly about R.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt catch that

Answer (score 0):

here it is with gsub (in a data.table), in case you need perl=TRUE, (fx look-ahead and look-behind), which does not work in str_match, unfortunately

```
dtx[, var_stringr := stringr::str_match(string, '([^_]+)(?:_[^_]+){5}$')[,2]][]


dtx[
  # first select the ones with '_' so that the third element is NA
  grepl('_', string), 
  var_gsub := sub('(.*_)([^_]+)(_[^_]+){5}$',  '\\2', string)][]
```

The disadvantage of this method is that if you select a number higher than the nth occurence, instead of giving back NA like str_match, it gives back the whole string.