# Split and concenate strings in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Lets say i have the following data:

```
kat  = c("a.b.c.d.e.f", "a.c.e.d.f.s", "a.v")
```

Desired output in base R:

```
> splitted = strsplit(kat, "[.]")
> kat2 = sapply(splitted, function(x) paste(x[1:min(5, length(x))], collapse = "."))
> kat2
[1] "a.b.c.d.e" "a.c.e.d.f" "a.v"
```

**Question: How to do it with data.table (in a "readable" way):**

I know how to do it technically correct:

```
dat = data.table(kat = kat)
dat[, kat := sapply(strsplit(kat, "[.]"), 
                    function(x) paste(x[1:min(5, length(x))], collapse = "."))]
```

But i find it not really readable, especially if i do it for longer operations.

Do I have to create a function for each of these operations?

```
kat3 = function(str){
  splitted = strsplit(str, "[.]")
  sapply(splitted, function(x) paste(x[1:min(5, length(x))], collapse = "."))
}

dat[, kat := kat3(kat)][]
```

or is it possible to do this within the indexing of the data.table?

```
dat[, kat := function(kat){
  splitted = strsplit(kat, "[.]")[[1]]
  paste(splitted[1:min(5, length(splitted))], collapse = ".")
  }, ]
```

Comment: For the data you posted you would get the same result with `substr(kat, 1, 10)` or `dat[, kat := substr(kat, 1, 10)]` in a data.table.

Comment: Actually `substr(kat, 1, 9)` :)

Comment: `sapply` can be alright for interactive sessions, but don't use it for programming.  Use `vapply` to encode the fact you know the output's dimensions and type.

Comment: @RonakShah You can give a range for number of matches, so your solution works with a tiny edit: `stringr::str_extract(kat, "^(([^\\.]*\\.){0,4}[^\\.]*)")`.

Comment: @NathanWerth ohh..yeah right. Thank you. I am not sure though if I should post it as an answer or not.

Comment: @RonakShah i would upvote if you add it as an answer. It is an interesting Approach for my "minimal dataset example" that i didnt think of,.....i didnt account in my example, that it should be generalized for more than one character. e.g. `"a.bb.c.de.e"`. Uncomplete spec my bad :/ I was aiming for `Do I have to create a function for each of these operations? [...] or is it possible to do this within the indexing of the data.table?`,...With the risk of being closed for `too broad`.

Answer (score 1):

You last attempt fails because you need to return a vector to kat. `sapply` or `Vectorize` can help for that.

```r
kat <- c("a.b.c.d.e.f", "a.c.e.d.f.s", "a.v")
library(data.table)
dat = data.table(kat = kat)

# error - function take a first element and return its transformation
dat[, kat2 := function(kat){
   splitted = strsplit(kat, "[.]")[[1]]
   paste(splitted[1:min(5, length(splitted))], collapse = ".")
}, ]
#> Error in `[.data.table`(dat, , `:=`(kat2, function(kat) {: RHS of assignment is not NULL, not an an atomic vector (see ?is.atomic) and not a list column.

smt <- function(kat){
   splitted = strsplit(kat, "[.]")[[1]]
   paste(splitted[1:min(5, length(splitted))], collapse = ".")
}

# to confirm
smt(kat)
#> [1] "a.b.c.d.e"

# use vectorize or sapply
smt_v <- Vectorize(smt)
smt_v(kat)
#> a.b.c.d.e.f a.c.e.d.f.s         a.v 
#> "a.b.c.d.e" "a.c.e.d.f"       "a.v"
sapply(kat, smt)
#> a.b.c.d.e.f a.c.e.d.f.s         a.v 
#> "a.b.c.d.e" "a.c.e.d.f"       "a.v"
```

If it is to be done to many variables you can loop through them or use lapply and .SDcols argument. If there are many transformations writing a `function.R` script and sourcing it might be the best way for further studies. :)

Answer (score 1):

A different way to solve the problem using regex where we extract word until nth occurrence of a character (here a dot). This avoids splitting and joining step of the string.

Taking regex help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38375205/3962914) and @Nathan Werth

```
library(data.table)
dat[, kat1 := stringr::str_extract(kat, "^(([^\\.]*\\.){0,4}[^\\.]*)")]

dat
#           kat      kat1
#1: a.b.c.d.e.f a.b.c.d.e
#2: a.c.e.d.f.s a.c.e.d.f
#3:         a.v       a.v
```